# how to filter an array containing the nsDictionary and add those filtered elements into an array ,,in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

in my iphone app i am working with NSDictionary

i have a Array which contains a dictionary like this

```
arrSelectedVersions(
        {
        CellStateKey = 0;
        CellTextKey = Airlines;
    },
        {
        CellStateKey = 1;
        CellTextKey = Audit;
    }
)
```

now i need to pic the values for the key 'CellTextKey' n i should add those values into an array, how can i do this  can any buddy help me,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *dict in arrSelectedVersions)
{
[newArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"CellTextKey"]];
}
```